# Why isn't the letter 'W' used to describe co-ordinates?

Tags: etymology

From my understanding, UV is used to describe the co-ordinates for 2 dimension and XYZ is used to describe the co-ordinates for 3 dimension.

why was the letter 'W' skipped which is between these 2? Is there any reasons pertaining to the English language or there is no real reason for the choice?

Comment: X and Y are the coordinates in 2 dimensions.

Comment: When texturing, it is addressed as UV mapping where UV is used to describe the 2D texture. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping

Comment: Did you look at "note 1" in your Wikipedia link? "When using quaternions (which is standard), 'W' is also used; cf. UVW mapping". Though I have no idea what that actually means.

Comment: In the Aerospace field, u,v,w are often used to express velocities along the x,y,z body axes respectively.  (And p,q,r are used to represent body axis rotational rates.) I agree with Oldcat, I've never heard of uv for 2D coordinate systems as any sort of a standard.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming conventions, not English, despite the question's attempt to relate itself to English usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` was apparently selected by Descartes' printer because is isn't very common in French, 'y' and 'z' naturally followed.

W is used for [homogenous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogenous_coordinates). There are areas of geometry where it is convenient to represent 3 dimensions with 4 numbers (so you can rotate and translate by a single 4x4 matrix) the last position is called `w`